# Frequent crashes during rendering using handlers

Tags: python, animation, scripting

I am using blender to create mathematical animations, and I usually need parametric surfaces changing every frame. I succeed to do this using python scripts and handlers, and here is the code for an animated sphere:

```
import bpy
import math

def my_handler(scene):

    Name="Sphere"

    def Mov(t):
        if t <= 0:
            return 0
        if t > 0 and t < 1:
            return (math.tanh(-1/t-1/(t-1))+1)/2
        if t >= 1:
            return 1

    # Deselect all
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    if bpy.data.objects.get(Name) is not None:
        obj = bpy.data.objects[Name]
        bpy.context.collection.objects.unlink(obj)
        bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)

    # mesh arrays
    verts = []
    faces = []

    # mesh variables
    numX = 40
    numY = 360

    # get frame value
    frame = bpy.context.scene.frame_current

    s1 = Mov((frame-400)/100)
    centerX=0
    centerY=0
    centerZ=-(1-s1)*10000+0*(1-s1)
    radius=(1-s1)*9998+2

    # fill verts array
    for i in range (0, numX):
        for j in range(0,numY):
            # nomalize range
        
            u = 2*math.pi*i/(numX-1)
            v = math.pi*(j/(numY-1)-1/2)

            x = centerX+radius*math.cos(u)*math.cos(v)
            y = centerY+radius*math.sin(u)*math.cos(v)
            z = centerZ+radius*math.sin(v)

            vert = (x,y,z)
            verts.append(vert)

    # fill faces array
    count = 0
    for i in range (0, numY *(numX-1)):
        if count < numY-1:
            A = i
            B = i+1
            C = (i+numY)+1
            D = (i+numY)
            face = (A,B,C,D)
            faces.append(face)
            count = count + 1
        else:
            count = 0

    # create mesh and object
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(Name)
    object = bpy.data.objects.new(Name,mesh)

    # set mesh location
    object.location = (0,0,0) #bpy.context.scene.cursor.location
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)

    # create mesh from python data
    mesh.from_pydata(verts,[],faces)
    mesh.update(calc_edges=True)

    # assign a material to the newly created curve
    mat = bpy.data.materials.get("GlossyWhite")
    object.data.materials.append(mat)

    # active smooth shading to object
    bpy.data.objects[Name].select_set(True)    
    bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
# Add the handler to handlers
bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_pre.append(my_handler)
```

Here are the different steps of the code. I create a function that will be part of the pre frame handlers. It starts to delete the object, and recreates it using parametric equations and frame positions. And then, it assigns to it properties and materials.

Everything seems to work nicely in the render viewport, the parametric surfaces just transform as expected when i control the frame cursor, but when i try to render the animation, it crashes randomly after a few frames.

Comment: Have on many occasions written _"Don't mix context and handlers"_  The scene is passed to the handler, _ie_ there is no need for `context.scene` and definitely do not use operators in handlers. (Might work in UI, but will fail, and possibly fail horribly on render)

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks for the reply ! So what can I use instead of `context.scene`for this purpose ?

Comment: You can avoid creating, deleting, recreating spheres. Just use the same object and bmesh, you have the same amount of verts. also you can precalculate everything into shapekey instead. also you might be able to use Extra Objects math tools (xyz function, etc) instead

Comment: @HananBeer Thank you ! I'll try to see how this works on the manual.

Comment: `def my_handler(` **scene** `)`